# CLojure sax parser examples

Tags: xml, clojure, sax

I've been using `xml-seq` for XML Parsing in a project and wondered if it's possible to use a sax parser instead. I've found there is a function called `startparse-sax`, but I can't find any examples for it? Does anyone have or know of any simple examples using `startparse-sax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little bit confusing. First of all, `xml-seq` is not for parsing. It is designed to be used on the output from `clojure.xml/parse` and returns a sequence of all nodes in the XML tree. Secondly, clojure.xml/parse is built on top of SAX, so if you are using `clojure.xml/parse` you are already using SAX indirectly. You can find examples on how to use it here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.xml/parse

It is also possible to give `clojure.xml/parse` a specific SAX parser if you don't want the default one. You do this by providing a "`startparse`" function to be used instead of the default `startparse-sax`. Here is an example on how to use the TagSoup HTML parser (which is exposed as a SAX parser) with `clojure.xml/parse`: https://gist.github.com/2378475 . (This is similar to what Enlive does.)